# Remote Upload To Google Drive by DRIVE API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

How to upload a file to Google Drive using the API by a url(Remote Upload)? I read the doc and I did not find any option like DropBox where `save_url()` can be used to remote upload.

But, there are a lot of sites which allows remote upload to Google Drive, so it must be possible.

Comment: I think you have to download the file first and then upload it. Those sites you mention probably do this part for you, before sending the info to Google. The only difference with Dropbox is that they integrated such functionality into an endpoint themselves, instead of letting 3rd parties provide it. Unless of course you can find something in the Drive API documentation which relates to it, I'm not going to research it on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [tutorial](https://github.com/J05HI/google-drive-direct-remote-upload) on how to directly upload files from the web to Google Drive without saving them completely on the server before. This is useful to upload files, which are bigger than the storage available on the server.

> How to use it:
>
> - Rename `"credentials/oauth-credentials_EXAMPLE.json"` to `"credentials/oauth-credentials.json"`
> - Download your oauth2 credentials in the google developer console and copy it in it
> - Call the `"index.php"` from the console (`"php index.php"`)
> - Follow the messages in the console window
> - Create pull requests to help with the development

Hope this helps!

Comment: The library you mentioned doesn't avoid the process of saving the file into your own machine before uploading to google.